# ajax call to php to get database rows

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

The following is in my **file.js**

```
function mainget(){
    $.ajax({    
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'example.php',
          data:json,
          success:function(data){
          }
    });       
}
```

**example.php**

```
<?php 
     $con = mysqli_connect('address','DATBASE','pass','futureday');
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $futureday");          
     $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                             
     echo json_encode($array); 
?>
```

I have been struck with this for the past 2 days. I have tried inserting alert as first line of function mainget , which is successful, but after that I get nothing.

Comment: whats `json`? add `alert();` into success: and debug it!

Comment: either use mysql or mysqli dont mix both . better to use mysqli.

Comment: What output are you getting is it ajax call or not?

Comment: post full mainget() to help u. and what is json ? is it data or datatype???

Comment: I am trying the suggestions from all, I have changed the mysql to mysqli, thanks ghost. I have now changed data to dataType,Thanks to Sherin. That is the full mainget()

Comment: if u r not passing data then why u have defined datatype????

Comment: i need the data to fill an html table

Answer (score 1):

You are using `data` property in AJAX call to indicate the json data type. It is an invalid one. Use `dataType` to provide the data type. `data` property is used to pass the datas. And also put quotes to the values like:

```
dataType:'json'
```

Also change your *example.php* file. There you are using `mysqli_connect` to connect the database, then `mysql_*` to execute and fetch operations. It is not correct. Use either `mysqli_*` or `mysql_*`. Edit as:

```
<?php 
     $con = mysqli_connect('address','DATBASE','pass','futureday');
     $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $futureday");          
     $response  = array();
     while($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
         $response[]=$array;
     }
     echo json_encode($response); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I did not downvote you. But I think the question has problems in both php and js side. Please try to add more info on this.

Comment: Then y don't the answer

Comment: I don't understand, you want to me to answer the question. I think user3240828 mixed mysqli and mysql statments, and ofcourse what you said on dataType:'json' is also one of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('address','DATBASE','pass','futureday');
           $query = "SELECT * FROM $futureday";  
           $results=$mysqli->query($query) ;        
           $res=$mysqli->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            echo json_encode($res);
```